# is there a way to add automatically buttons on each element of a generated list?

Tags: javascript, html, database, button

I'm working on a web app that lets people schedule lessons and timeslots, and I'm trying to make it so that people can click on the timeslot to accept it. Currently, the table is retrieved from the database and generated with this code:

```
function updateSchedules(name = "missing", grade = "missing", date = "missing", time = "missing", status = "missing", id) {
    let table = document.getElementById('schedules');
    let color;

    console.log("Output schedule for " + name);

    if (status.toLowerCase() === 'pending') {
        color = "background-color:rgb(252, 38, 0)";
    } else if (status.toLowerCase() === 'confirmed') {
        color = 'background-color:rgb(0, 255, 13)';
    } else {
        color = 'background-color:rgb(35, 64, 153)';
    }

    table.innerHTML += `
    <tr>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${grade}</td>
        <td id=testday2>${date}</td>
        <td id=testtime2>${time}</td>
        <td style="${color}">${status}</td>
    </tr>`;
}
```

Is there a way to add buttons on each row of the table that refers to each row's unique id without just making buttons and adding event listeners manually for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add one more `<td>` tag with `<button>` tag and bind with onlick event and pass unique_id in function parameter like this:

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="myfunc(${id})"></button></td>
```

> ${id} may be string or number it's depend on requirements

`Note-:`

1. You have to pass unique id from (backend).
2. unique_id might be primary key of database row.

Then write script to handle button like-:

```
<script>
  function myfunc(unique_id){
     console.log(unique_id);
     // do something
  }
<script>
```

More appropriate if you use anchor tag with button like-:

```
<td><a onclick="myfunc(${id}")><button type="button"></button></a></td>
```

> There are multiple ways to do this same thing. More appropriate if you use `this` keyword with jquery instead of write pure javascript.